# Null Reference in file

Tags: c#

I am getting and error on this line:

```
String selectedValue = this.employeeList.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

The error I am getting is

> NullReferenceException was unhandled.

What does this mean? Can someone help me understand why I am getting this error.  Down below is the whole code.

```
String filePath = this.txtFilePath.Text;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No file path specified");
}

if (this.employeeList.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    String selectedValue = this.employeeList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(selectedValue);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No item selected");
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at your `filePath` test; it's not doing what you think.

Comment: @geekosaur called mistake number 1. Number 2 is if you don't have anything in filepath, probably shouldn't try to save anything to it...

Comment: but he mentioned that he is getting error in that particular line of code.

Comment: Well thats where I am getting confused about cause I cant put C:\ becuase they can pull files from anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means you are trying to access something which is null (not initialized to any valid value). So add a null check before accessing that.

I guess in this case, the `employeeList.SelectedValue` is probably null.

```
String selectedValue = string.Empty;
if(this.employeeList.SelectedValue!=null)
{
  selectedValue = this.employeeList.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please select any value");
}
```

If you run into any such errors , **Always use Visual Studio Breakpoints  and Step thru line by line** to see what values are coming and where it is breaking. That is the best way to understand what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

It means that this.employeeList.SelectedValue has a null value.

A null object (SelectedValue) has no methods, so you can't call .ToString() on it.

Investigate why this.employeeList.SelectedValue would be null and you will find the source of your problem.